# Why doesn't this average function in haskell work?

Tags: haskell, types, casting

I wanted to make a simple average (mean) function in Haskell, so I tried the following in ghci:

```
ghci> let avg xs = (sum xs) / (length xs)
```

And it throws the following error:

```
No instance for (Fractional Int)
  arising from a use of `/'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
In the expression: (sum xs) / (length xs)
In an equation for `avg': avg xs = (sum xs) / (length xs)
```

So, I decided to break it down by trying the following:

```
ghci> let a = (sum [1,2])
ghci> let b = (length [1,2])
```

That all works good.

So then I tried the following

```
ghci> a/b
```

And I got the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Int'
In the second argument of `(/)', namely `b'
In the expression: a / b
In an equation for `it': it = a / b
```

So, in Haskell are `Integer` and `Int` different? - And if so, how can I make the original function work?

Comment: Needs more `fromIntegral`. =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

but

```
(/) :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
```

So, when you say `whatever / length xs`, it doesn't type, because Int is not a Fractional number type! This is what the "No instance for..." error is trying to tell you. This definition will work:

```
GHCi> let avg xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Here, we use `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` to convert the Int we get from `length` into a Fractional number. Note that the resulting function will only work on lists of Fractional numbers because of this (but e.g. `avg [1,2,3]` will still work fine).

To explain the error you get when doing it "in pieces", it's because in `let a = sum [1,2]`, the list's elements are Integers, so their sum is an Integer, but in `let b = length [1,2]`, the resulting length is an Int, per the type of `length` I showed above. So, when you do `a/b`, this fails way before it even realises that Int and Integer are not instances of Fractional — since `(/)` takes two arguments of the same type, it can't possibly work.

And yes, Integer and Int are different — Int is a fixed-precision integral type, usually the size of a numeric word, like `long` in C, whereas Integer is an arbitrary-precision bignum, capable of storing any integer; or at least, any integer that'll fit into your RAM :)

Another possible approach would be to define `avg xs` as `sum xs / genericLength xs`, using [`Data.List.genericLength`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:genericLength), which works with any numeric type, not just Ints:

```
genericLength :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
```

For that, you'll have to `import Data.List` in GHCi. Yet another possible approach (but one resulting in a different function altogether) would be to use integer division: `` let avg xs = sum xs `div` length xs `` (note: `` a `div` b `` is just `div a b`; this syntactic sugar works for every function).

Comment: Since you're defining `avg` with an argument, i.e. `let avg xs = ...`, the monomorphism restriction does not apply, and no defaulting is done. Indeed, the type of `avg` as defined is `(Fractional a) => [a] -> a`. The type is, however, defaulted to `Double` if you try using it with e.g. `avg [1.5, 2]`.